# How to resolve `Failed to create NAT chain DOCKER` as Reboot not working?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, debian

Here is my OS

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Docker version

```
Docker version 20.10.5+dfsg1, build 55c4c88
```

Docker-compose

```
docker-compose version 1.25.3, build d4d1b42b
```

Here is the problem

I want to install Docker and `docker-compose` on my server following this instruction
`https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/`

However, I can not stat the Docker, here is the log

Run

```
systemctl status docker.service
```

Got

```
Mar 12 10:27:02 trigan4gb systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Mar 12 10:27:02 trigan4gb systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 12 10:27:02 trigan4gb systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 12 10:27:02 trigan4gb systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 12 10:27:02 trigan4gb systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Run
`dockerd`

Got

```
INFO[2023-03-12T10:32:11.180456435-04:00] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument
```

I tried `Reboot` it but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run :
`apt update`
`apt upgrade`

then `reboot`

It works again